# anchor navigation on side-nav isn't working

Tags: html, navigation, anchor, nav, sections

[page with slide overlay side navigation bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtuyT.jpg)

I've designed a website with side nav bar at the right side as shown in the attached picture.
HTML code :

```
<ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#ourpurpose">Purpose</a></li>
      <li><a href="#vision2030">Vision 2030</a></li>
```

also as shown in the body in the left side is one `<section>` of 3 more sections as a sample, which contain titles an paragraphs.
the code :

```
    <div class="left" id="ourpurpose">
              <ul class="grid">
                <li class="col-6-12 left cell-32">
                  <h1 class="title">Our Purpose<h1>
                  <p>...</p>
...
```

when nav is active the body zoom out as its on separate layer..so the anchor `<a>` isn't working, I need a way to make each title in the nav bar on-click to take me to the specified title regarding which section the `<h1>` is in the body.

Comment: Please create a simplified code sample to demonstrate the issue. with the given code, this should work

Comment: yes it's working when `<a href=" ">` direct to a section, but i need to go to a specific title in the section.

Comment: Add an id to the title and link to it?

Comment: tried Naming & ID'ing everythin and yet it doesn't work unless it's a section.

Comment: Please refer to my first comment then